# Eclipse CDT Auto Include Shared Libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I am working in Eclipse: Helios Service Release 1 using Eclipse CDT compiling using g++

I have just started to have a go at using Shared Libraries in my projects but have run into a little problem. I have three projects A, B and C. A and B are both Shared Libraries and C is an executable.

Under eclipse I have managed to reference A and B from C and C compiles and runs correctly but when I try and run the generated C program manually outside of Eclipse I get the following error:

"**error while loading shared libraries: libA.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**"

I have tried moving A.so B.so and C into the same folder and run C but I get the same error.

Can I get Eclipse to build my project with all the files in the same place and them still run when I move them to a new location?

Comment: I seem to have the exact same problem, I have libA in the linker, it is also listed under Paths and Symbols --> Library paths. Does the location for libA need to be in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well? I am able to compile and run outside of eclipse (from an exterm)

Comment: @Anu I found this blog to be very helpful http://dirkraffel.com/2008/06/27/developing-shared-libraries-with-eclipse-cdt/ regarding linking in Eclipse but it didn't really solve my problem when I was exporting.

Answer (score 8):

Run `ldconfig` as root to update the cache - if that still doesn't help, you need to add the path to the file `ld.so.conf` (just type it in on its own line) or better yet, add the entry to a new file (easier to delete) in directory `ld.so.conf.d`.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the folder in which the shared libraries are.
Something like this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/lib/`