# error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface

I'm making a C program which is connecting a oracle DB. I have correctly installed the Oracle Instant Client and ocilib.

And I did compile the code without any error but when I executing the program I got following error.

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If anyone know how to solve please write it
Thank you.

Comment: Did you do step 3 of [the installation instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html])? Showing the compilation/linking commands you used might be helpful, as well as the relevant environment variables for your platform.

Answer (score 6):

Yes I solve it by adding a link of the library to the `/usr/lib`.

using the following command.

```
sudo ln -s /home/INSTANT_CLIENT/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup LD_LIBRARY

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/instantclient:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

like

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/oracle/instantclient_21_4:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me in compiling a Pro*C program on OL 8 with Oracle DB client 19.16.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Examples CD is installed.
Make sure environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set, and the library file is accessible (permission-wise) for the user who you are logged in as.

If you have checked these and still get the error, please post the output of:
    `strace ./a.out`

Answer (score 0):

LIBPATH environment variable should be pointed to the lib32 folder which contains the libclntsh.

then you need to export LIBPATH variable before you run your application.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from my answer here: [Eclipse CDT Auto Include Shared Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327744/eclipse-cdt-auto-include-shared-libraries/9368199#9368199)

> Run **ldconfig** as root to update the cache - if that still doesn't
>   help, you need to add the path to the file ld.so.conf (just type it in
>   on its own line) or better yet, add the entry to a new file (easier to
>   delete) in directory ld.so.conf.d.