# could not load a library

Tags: linux, installation, shared-libraries

I am using a tool that repeatedly returns an error saying that it cannot load a library file (`libppl.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`) at `<path_to_file>`. The thing is that the required file is actually there.

I've tried setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, adding entries to `ld.so.conf` and `ld.so.conf.d` and then running ldconfig, which are solutions I found on the links provided bellow. The problem, however, is still there. When running `ldconfig -v`, I can see that it looks at the file directory but does not populate the cache for any of the `so` files in the directory, including the one at `<path_to_file>`.

What could be the problem?

useful links:

[cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172621/cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

[Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)

Answer (score 2):

The tool may be 32 bits and you've the 64 bits version of the library.
You can check the binary architecture via the `file` command.

Also, you can force the library via [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)