# Capistrano deploy rails fails on nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, nokogiri, rbenv

I get the following error when deploying to Ubuntu using:

```
ruby '2.3.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.5.1'
gem 'rake', '~> 11.3'
gem 'capistrano',  '~> 3.9'
```

This is my server log:

```
00:29 deploy:assets:precompile
01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
01 rake aborted!
01 LoadError: libruby.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fog-xml-0.1.3/lib/fog/xml.rb:2:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fog-xml-0.1.3/lib/fog/xml.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fog-aws-1.4.1/lib/fog/aws.rb:2:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fog-aws-1.4.1/lib/fog/aws.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/releases/20171121132549/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/releases/20171121132549/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/releases/20171121132549/Rakefile:4:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/releases/20171121132549/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
01 /home/myapp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
01 LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/2.3/nokogiri
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:30:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fog-xml-0.1.3/lib/fog/xml.rb:2:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fog-xml-0.1.3/lib/fog/xml.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fog-aws-1.4.1/lib/fog/aws.rb:2:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fog-aws-1.4.1/lib/fog/aws.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/releases/20171121132549/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/releases/20171121132549/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/releases/20171121132549/Rakefile:4:in `require'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/releases/20171121132549/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/myappWeb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
01 /home/myapp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
01 /home/myapp/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172621/cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory#9368228 this is for c++ but I would give it a read

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you try to run `gem install nokogiri` from your app directory on your server?
You might be missing some librairies on your server. See http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: I uninstalled and installed nokogiri again on both my local machine and the server. None fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the entire ubuntu system on the server. Then reinstalled ruby and bundler. Everything worked after this.