# Failed in using LD_PRELOAD to hook mmap system call in qemu(through libvirt)

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

I want to hook mmap system call in qemu, and I use libvirt to passthrough the environment argument like this:

```
<qemu:commandline>
  <qemu:env name='LD_PRELOAD' value='/glibcHookMMAP.so'/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

But it failed! I can hardly find out what is the matter! The log in libvirt like this:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/glibcHookMMAP.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

Firstly, I think it's the problem of authority. But the file glibcHookMMAP.so has been done with command `chmod 777`.

Environment:

Ubuntu 18.04.2 Linux 5.4.0-92

libvirt 4.0.0

qemu 2.11.1

Comment: Why the / in the path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172621/cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: / is a strange place to put the library.

Comment: '/' is the root path(maybe the problem of the parent directory permission...). By using LD_PRELOAD=/glibcHookMMAP.so qemu-system-x86_64 ...(args), it works! I think is not the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I know the solution: Apparmor policy in Ubuntu limits the work, is like the SELinux. Thus I should modify configuration in  /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu to allow libvirt to link .so.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).